# Swift - Use an enum to map UISegmentedControl

Tags: swift, enums

Using a three position segmented control representing seconds 60, 30 and 15. The code for an enum:

```
enum RefreshRate: Int {
    case sixty = 0
    case thirty
    case fifteen

    func refreshEvery() -> Double {
        switch self {
        case .sixty:    return 3600.0
        case .thirty:   return 1800.0
        case .fifteen:  return 900.0
        }
    }
}
```

used like:

```
let defaultValue = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "refreshRate")
let refreshInterval = RefreshRate(rawValue: defaultValue)?.refreshEvery()
```

works great.

Is there a more 'Swifty' way to get the integer 60 in the first case of the enum, without using the function or a switch statement?

Comment: BTW - What does this question have to do with UISegmentedController?

Comment: Even though that's not what you're asking: a more swifty way for `refreshEvery` would be: `var refreshInterval: Double { ... }`

Comment: @rmaddy In case someone was looking to store the index of the segmented control. Your answer provides a good alternative.

Comment: Your question make absolutely no mention that your enum was being used to represent the index of a segmented control. That would have been useful information. Your question makes it appear it is only being used to determine the number of seconds associated with the enum case.

Comment: @rmaddy That is why the first line of the enum is `case sixty = 0`. That would make thirty = 1 and fifteen = 2.

Comment: Basically you want each case to represents two values, an index and a duration. So one needs to be from the raw value and the other from a function.

Comment: @rmaddy  Yes, I want to represent 2 values, an index and a double.  Your deleted answer did answer seem to solve this.

Comment: My answer only supported one value per case - the duration, not the index. Since I can't think of a better general approach over what you are already doing, my answer didn't really seem to help your clarified question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a *computed property* to return the value for `refreshEvery`:

```
enum RefreshRate: Int {
    case sixty = 0
    case thirty
    case fifteen

    var refreshEvery: Double {
        return 60 * [60, 30, 15][self.rawValue]
    }
}

let rate = RefreshRate.sixty

print(rate.rawValue)     // 0
print(rate.refreshEvery) // 3600.0
```

Comment: This looks like an in-the-middle solution.  More simple, yet still must use a property.  I am looking at `case sixty = 60`, storing the rawValue in user defaults and retrieving that with `UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "refreshRate")`.

Comment: How will you then map that to the segmented control index?

Comment: This is where my idea will fall apart - your answer is valid.