# Set the titles of a UISegmentedControl (built in IB, not code) from enum

Tags: ios, swift, enums, uisegmentedcontrol

I have an enum that I use to describe the subjective accuracy of a quantity.

```
enum MeasurementAccuracy: Int {

    typealias RawValue = Int

    case pending = 0
    case approximate = 1
    case atLeast = 2
    case exact = 3

    var description: String {

        switch self {

        case .pending:      return "pending"
        case .approximate:  return "approximate"
        case .atLeast:      return "at least"
        case .exact:        return "exact"
        }
    }
}
```

(The quantity may relate to a variety of different real-world "objects", for example the measurement of 500 seeds, which might be *approximate*, or the measurement of 30 seedlings, which might be *at least*, or the measurement of 12 plants, which might be *accurate/exact*.)

I decided to use a segmented control in a custom `UITableViewCell` to allow the user to select the `MeasurementAccuracy` for their measurement.

It's a UISegmentedControl with 4 segments, built in a storyboard.

[image: screenshot of UISegmentedControl in storyboard]

I know I can assign headings for each of these segments by:

1. typing the string into the Attributes Inspector of the storyboard...

   [image: screenshot of Attributes Inspector]
2. writing the titles individually...

   `segmentedControl.setTitle("pending", forSegmentAt: 0)`

I've done some reading:

- [Swift - Use an enum to map UISegmentedControl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50164410/1883707)
- [Swift Guide to Map Filter Reduce](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/)
- [Swift enums and UISegmentedControl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50164410/1883707)

I'm guessing my actual problem is that I'm struggling to get my head around the use of advanced loop functions (e.g. `.map`) on collections.

It's seems I'm making life difficult for myself, however I want to learn how to set the titles efficiently in code, from an enum (or other), so that in future, more complicated multi-use cases can be dealt with simply.

I'm stuck. Any thoughts, hints or solutions?

---

**UPDATE**

CUSTOM CELL class:

```
protocol DelegateForPickerAccuracy: class {
    func accuracy(_ selectedSegmentIndex: Int?)
}

class TableViewCell_SegmentedControl: UITableViewCell {

    // MARK: - Public Properties

    weak var delegateForPickerAccuracy: DelegateForPickerAccuracy?

    // MARK: - IB Outlets & Actions

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl! 
    @IBAction func segmentedControlActionChangeValue(_ sender: Any) {
        delegateForPickerAccuracy?.accuracy(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `CaseIterable` to the enum `MeasurementAccuracy`

```
enum MeasurementAccuracy: Int, CaseIterable {
    case pending = 0, approximate = 1, atLeast = 2, exact = 3    
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .pending:      return "pending"
        case .approximate:  return "approximate"
        case .atLeast:      return "at least"
        case .exact:        return "exact"
        }
    }
}
```

//UISegmentedControl created programmatically

And initialize the UISegmentedControl with `.allCases` property.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: MeasurementAccuracy.allCases.map { $0.description.capitalized })
    view.addSubview(segmentedControl)
    //add constraints or set frame for segmentedControl
}
```

//UISegmentedControl created in storyboard

Or if you have the segment control in the storyboard, enumerate the `MeasurementAccuracy.allCases` array and insert a segment for each element

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    segmentControl.removeAllSegments()
    MeasurementAccuracy.allCases.forEach {
        segmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: $0.description.capitalized, at: segmentedControl.numberOfSegments, animated: false)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is very helpful thanks, but as noted, I have instantiated the `UISegmentedControl` in a storyboard for a custom `UITableViewCell`. I'm guessing that your solution will work for a control created in code, from a `UITableViewController` file? How would I do this via `@IBOutlet` in a custom cell (that does not have lifecycle methods such as `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @andrewbuilder I've added solutions for programmatically created and created in storyboard. Check it

Comment: Yes thanks, your answer is helpful, but it does not address that I am attempting to execute this in a custom `UITableViewCell` which does not have `UITableViewController` lifecycle methods. I'll add some more detail to my question to make that clear.

Comment: @andrewbuilder you should create an `IBOutlet` for the segment control and add the above code in `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: @andrewbuilder If you add `CaseIterable' protocol to the enum, you can use `Enum.allCases` to get all the cases in an array. You don't need any extra functions such as `allValues()`

Comment: OK point taken, thanks for clarifying. But it works the same as `allValues`, without having to implement that protocol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197161/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-andrewbuilder).

Comment: Also your code cannot be added into `viewDidLoad` because I am using a custom cell. Also, the `.insertSegment` method adds another four segments to my existing control. What I am wanting, is to change the title of the four existing segments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rajesh for pointing me in the right direction...

To be clear...

Using code, I want to set the **titles** of an existing segmented control, that is embedded in a **custom** `UITableViewCell`, noting specifically that the control and the custom cell are built in IB / storyboard.

The following code works perfectly...

As suggested by Rajesh, adopt `CaseIterable` protocol in the enum:

```
enum MeasurementAccuracy: Int, CaseIterable {...}
```

Then use the `.setTitle` convenience method within the `MeasurementAccuracy.allCases.forEach` iteration:

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl! {

    didSet {
        MeasurementAccuracy.allCases.forEach {
            segmentedControl.setTitle($0.description, forSegmentAt: $0.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe because of `CaseIterable` protocol, no need for `typealias RawValue = Int` in the enum, but not certain on that. Please comment if you know otherwise.